# Possible to email an .ics file without creating it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icalendar, ruby-on-rails-5

My app needs to send emails to users with an .ics attachment.

Currently I have an action that renders a .ics-file when users click a link on a web page:

```
def invite
  cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
  cal.event do |e|
    e.dtstart     = Icalendar::Values::Date.new('20050428')
    e.dtend       = Icalendar::Values::Date.new('20050429')
    e.summary     = "Meeting with the man."
    e.description = "Have a long lunch meeting and decide nothing..."
    e.ip_class    = "PRIVATE"
  end
  cal.publish
  render text: cal.to_ical 
end
```

Link:

```
<%= link_to 'Download .ics file with right click', invite_path(format: :ics) %>
```

Is it at all possible, in the same manner, to provide an ics-attachment to an email without first creating/saving the file and then refering to the path?

If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to send the file using a mailer attachment. Set the mime type to `text/calendar` and use `.to_ical` for the file content.

Pass in the `cal` variable to the mailer.

```
def invite
  cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
  cal.event do |e|
    e.dtstart     = Icalendar::Values::Date.new('20050428')
    e.dtend       = Icalendar::Values::Date.new('20050429')
    e.summary     = "Meeting with the man."
    e.description = "Have a long lunch meeting and decide nothing..."
    e.ip_class    = "PRIVATE"
  end
  cal.publish
  InviteMailer.invite(current_user.email, cal).deliver_later # or .deliver_now
  render text: cal.to_ical
end
```

Setup the file attachment.

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def invite(recipient, cal)
    mail.attachments['invite.ics'] = { mime_type: 'text/calendar', content: cal.to_ical }
    mail(to: recipient, subject: 'Invite')
  end
end
```

(I did not test this.)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer%3a%3aBase-label-Attachments
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html